# populating a dropdownlist in a gridview from an array source

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, gridview

i have been trying to populate dropdownlist in my gridview from an array source but it seems to read just the first array element . I tried doing it with a panel and it worked .Here is my code.

```
       public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
       {
       DataTable dtnew = new DataTable();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string[] excel = new string[10];
        DataTable dtt = (DataTable)Session["griddata"];
        for (int i = 0; i < dtt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            excel[i] = dtt.Columns[i].ColumnName; //column names from a datatable stored in the array
        }

        Session["exceldata"] = excel;


        string[] sqlcolumn = new string[10];
        DataTable dtt1 = (DataTable)Session["dbasecolumns"];
        for (int j = 0; j < dtt1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            sqlcolumn[j] = dtt1.Columns[j].ColumnName; //column names from a datatable stored in the array
        }
        Session["excel"] = sqlcolumn;

        DropDownList drd = new DropDownList();
        dtnew.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("database", typeof(string)));
        dtnew.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("excel", typeof(string)));
       // DataRow dr = new DataRow();
        foreach (String colname in sqlcolumn)
        {


            drd.Items.Add(colname);
          //  drd.Items.Add(new ListItem(colname));


        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sqlcolumn.Length; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dtnew.NewRow();
            dtnew.Rows.Add(dr);
            {


                dr["excel"] = string.Empty;
                dr["database"] = drd;
            }

        }
        //Panel1.Controls.Add(drd);


       GridView1.DataSource = dtnew;
       GridView1.DataBind();

    }
    }
```

It seems to fill my GridView Column with just the first element of the array and that too as a simple text (not as dropdownlist).How can i possibly achieve this.

Thanks In advance

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but the little things in your code bugs me. The arrays excel and sqlcolumn, you give them static length but in the loop below, you use a dynamic expression. This is wrong because what if the length of dtt or dtt1 is over 10? Declare both arrays after the tables, and use dtt.Columns.Count and dtt1.Columns.Count instead of 10.

Comment: You are trying in wrong way. In GridView_DataBound find the dropdown, set it's datasource and bind it.

Comment: I cannot use it in GridView_databound because i need to load the gridview on page load event (navigated from other page) 
Thanks